# using Contact.NICKNAME

Tags: java, blackberry

I am trying to read out the Nickname of a Contact in a BlackBerry Java app but the method call

```
getPIMList().isSupportedField(BlackBerryContact.NICKNAME)
```

always tells me that the Field is not supported.

Am I doing something wrong or is it really not supported? Because the devices I am testing on allow me to add a Nickname field in the address book.

Comment: yes u r right even i found the same